# How to pull image from Android device using command line?

Tags: android, adb, retrofit2

I am trying to pull an image from device. This is the command I used:

```
hesam: Desktop $ adb kill-server
hesam: Desktop $ adb root
* daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
* daemon started successfully *
adbd cannot run as root in production builds
hesam: Desktop $ adb pull /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/20170112_141004.jpg /home/hesam/Desktop/
```

The cursor moves to next line and nothing happens!

My main task is uploading the image to my back end. However, although I am able to assign this image to imageView (I can see it in imageView), Same things happens. Retrofit2 shows request is being sent but does not show end of request. So, I guess something is wrong with my image. That's why I am trying to pull it from my device.

```
D/OkHttp: --> POST https://flash.something.com/api/video/setAvatar http/1.1
D/OkHttp: Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=af005343-8ced-461e-81b9-fcf26b0aae86
D/OkHttp: Content-Length: 2208146
```